# how to adjust timestamp difference of client and server?

Tags: javascript, php

Which is the best way to display the "sent time" of message to user?
Is saving with "server side time() function" better or saving with "client side getTime()" and updating that value with ajax is better?

Comment: Generally you'd use the server time, as the user can set any date and time on his/her computer, making it not very reliable.

Comment: if server and client are in different timezones, either set the timezone to one of them to be same as the other or use a timezone difference (e.g +2 hours) and **adjust all dates accrordingly to one of them** (by adding/subtracting the timezone diff)

Comment: alternatively the client can always display dates as sent by the server and you are done

Comment: suppose we sent message at 4:39 but because of the server is in different timezone we ma display the sent time as 5:39.what to do to solve this?

Comment: You need to introduce some form of "locales" for your clients for this. You store timestamps according to server time and convert them on-the-fly according to the clients locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

if server and client are in different timezones, either set the timezone to one of them to be same as the other or use a timezone difference (e.g +2 hours) and **adjust all dates accrordingly to one of them** (by adding/subtracting the timezone diff)

alternatively the client can always display dates as sent by the server and you are done

e.g if you have the server timezone difference just display it in the client as such (and you dont need anything else, if that is good for your use case)

```
2016-01-03 17:12:00 (+1 GMT)
```

For your example:

add the timezone diff (+ 1 hour), in the client (or the server, but not both)

e.g in the server (php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php))

```
$server_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$client_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $server_date );
$client_date->add( new DateInterval('PT'.(60*60).'S') ) // + 1 hour
$client_date = $client_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or in the client (js use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [DateX](https://github.com/foo123/DateX))

```
var client_date = new Date(timestamp(server_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')+60*60*1000); // + 1 hour;
// timestamp is supposed to parse the date and return a unix timestamp in milliseconds
// for example if you use DateX, you can do:
// client_date = new DateX(DateX.fromString(server_date,'Y-m-d H:i:s').getTime()+60*60*1000).format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

A third option is for the server to always sent UTC (GMT) dates and let the client convert them to local/timezoned dates (sth similar to the above, only the client uses its own timezone offset instead of being hardcoded, e.g +1 Hour)

Answer (score 0):

The server is the only machine you have control over, so it is the only machine you can rely on. But beware of daylight savings time.

I'd recommend storing all dates on the server in UTC, and then converting to local time in the browser. Doing this will also help you account for daylight savings time changes, which occur at different times around the world.

To illustrate this, if you were doing this server side, then the following C# code converts UTC to the local time, accounting for daylight savings times:

```
DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, zone);
```

I know this is a PHP question, but I hope this code helps.